# How would I add a displayable highscore variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my game I have created a scoring system, but I am struggling to find a way to store a high score that doesn't reset when the `gameloop` is run again. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import timeit


pygame.init()

display_width = 1600
display_height = 850
speed = [1, -1]

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
grey = (177,177,177)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Kill hitler before he gets trump')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crosshairImg = pygame.image.load('crosshair.PNG')
hitlerImg = pygame.image.load('hitler.png')
donaldImg = pygame.image.load('donald.png')

def crosshair(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(crosshairImg, (x,y))

def enemy(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(hitlerImg, (x,y))

def friendly(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(donaldImg, (x,y))
def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',45)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def status(total, enemy_kills):
    if total == 0:
        status = 0
    else:
        status = round((enemy_kills/total)*100, 2)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render('Status:'+str(status)+'%', True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,30))

def score(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render('Confirmed Enemy Kills:'+str(count), True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def timer(count):
    count = round(count, 1)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render('time left:'+str(count), True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,45))

def friend_kill(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render('Confirmed Friendly Kills:'+str(count), True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,15))
```

I believe that the following part of the code needs editing. I showed you the previous to hopefully make the next part easier to read.

```
def gameloop():
    thing_startx = (display_width/2)
    thing_starty = (display_height/2)
    thing_xspeed = 0
    thing_yspeed = 0

    enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-20))
    enemy_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-20))
    enemy_xspeed = 0
    enemy_yspeed = 0

    friend_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-40))
    friend_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-40))
    friend_width = 40
    friend_height = 40
    friend_xspeed = 0
    friend_yspeed = 0

    ammo = 5

    kills = 0

    total_kills = 0

    friendly_kills = 0

    gameExit = False

    start = time.time()

    elapsed = 0

    while not gameExit and elapsed < 30:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                thing_startx = event.pos[0]-37
                thing_starty = event.pos[1]-37

        thing_startx += thing_xspeed
        thing_starty += thing_yspeed

        gameDisplay.fill (grey)
        score(kills)
        status(total_kills, kills)
        friend_kill(friendly_kills)
        timer((30-elapsed))

        enemy(enemy_startx, enemy_starty)
        friendly(friend_startx, friend_starty)
        crosshair(thing_startx, thing_starty)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (event.pos[0] > enemy_startx and event.pos[0] < enemy_startx+45) and event.pos[1] > enemy_starty and event.pos[1] < enemy_starty+60:
                enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-45))
                enemy_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-60))
                friend_startx = random.randrange(0,(display_width-40))
                friend_starty = random.randrange(0,(display_height-40))
                kills += 1
                total_kills += 1



        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (event.pos[0] > friend_startx and event.pos[0] < friend_startx+60) and event.pos[1] > friend_starty and event.pos[1] < friend_starty+80:
                friend_startx = random.randrange(0,(display_width-40))
                friend_starty = random.randrange(0,(display_height-40))
                enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-45))
                enemy_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-60))
                friendly_kills += 1
                total_kills += 1
                message_display('you killed a friendly')
                time.sleep(1)

        if (kills>=5 and kills<10) or (kills>=15 and kills<20):
            if enemy_startx+45<display_width and enemy_xspeed not in (1, -1):
                enemy_xspeed += 1
            if friend_startx+60<display_width and friend_xspeed not in (1,-1):
                friend_xspeed += 1

            if enemy_startx>0 and enemy_xspeed not in (-1, 0):
                enemy_xspeed = 1
            if friend_startx>0 and friend_xspeed not in (-1, 0):
                friend_xspeed = 1


        elif kills>=10 and kills<20:
            if enemy_starty+60<display_height and enemy_yspeed not in (1, -1):
                enemy_yspeed += 1
            if friend_starty+80<display_width and friend_yspeed not in (1,-1):
                friend_yspeed += 1

            if enemy_starty>0 and enemy_yspeed not in (-1, 0):
                enemy_yspeed = 1
            if friend_starty>0 and friend_yspeed not in (-1, 0):
                friend_yspeed = 1

        elif kills>=20:
            if enemy_startx+45<display_height and enemy_xspeed not in (2, -2):
                enemy_xspeed = 2
            if friend_startx+60<display_height and friend_xspeed not in (2, -2):
                friend_xspeed = 2


            if enemy_starty>0 and enemy_yspeed not in (2, -2):
                enemy_yspeed = -2
            if friend_starty>0 and friend_yspeed not in (2, -2):
                friend_yspeed = -2

        else:
            enemy_xspeed = 0
            enemy_yspeed = 0
            friend_xspeed = 0
            friend_yspeed = 0





        if enemy_startx+45>display_width or enemy_startx<0:
            enemy_xspeed *= -1
        if enemy_starty+60>display_height or enemy_starty<0:
            enemy_yspeed *= -1

        if friend_startx+40>display_width or friend_startx<0:
            friend_xspeed *= -1
        if friend_starty+40>display_height or friend_starty<0:
            friend_yspeed *= -1



        enemy_starty += enemy_yspeed        
        enemy_startx += enemy_xspeed
        friend_startx += friend_xspeed
        friend_starty += friend_yspeed

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        msg = 'you got',kills,'enemy kills amd',friendly_kills,'enemy kills'
    message_display('you got '+str(kills)+' enemy kills and '+str(friendly_kills)+' friendly kills')
    time.sleep(2)
    gameloop()



gameloop()
```

Comment: Too much code and it's not clear what's wrong with it or what's the part related to the high score.

Comment: @Goyo yes I understand. There is a reason why I have done this because I am new to coding and don't 100% know what is needed for people to know what I am doing. And 2 I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the high score in a separate .txt file called highscore.txt. .txt files are files that can store strings but also be used as data that doesn't get deleted. Make sure your .txt file is in the same directory as your game file. To start it up, write '0' on the first line without apostrophes. Does not require downloads or extra imports. Make a .txt file and do this in the game loop:

```
File = open(highscore.txt, 'r') #Out of game Loop
HighScore = int(File.read())       

if kills > HighScore:              #In game loop
    File.truncate()
    File.close()
    File = open(highscore.txt, 'w')
    File.write(kills)
    File.close()
    File = open(highscore.txt, 'r')
```

Comment: Tutorial Here: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: previous answer failed to answer the question.

At the top of the file import the pickle module:

```
import pickle
```

At the start of the game_loop() function write the following piece of code:

```
try:
    with open("var.pickle", "rb") as file:
        high = pickle.load(file)
except (OSError, IOError) as e:
    high = 0
    with open("var.pickle", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump( high, file)
```

Finally before the line

```
message_display('you got '+str(kills)+' enemy kills and '+str(friendly_kills)+' friendly kills')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Add the following:

```
if high < kills:
    with open("var.pickle", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(high, open("var.pickle", "wb"))
    message_display("New High-score!")
```

What happens is that you get the high score stored if it exists or create it with a score of 0. Once you finish the game loop if the score is higher than the high-score you change the  high-score to the new value.

Comment: `global kills = 0` isn't valid syntax

Comment: yes, LPK you are right. Sorry I had to remove the `global` keyword

Comment: I understand what you want me to do. But I fail to see how it will help.

Comment: It means that if you want to call the game loop function again the kills variable will stay unaffected

Comment: would this mean I will have to add kills to the function. e.g. type it as gameloop(kills)

Comment: I edited the answer to match your needs

Comment: @ClaymoreAdrendamar. When I first run this it works perfectly. However when I try to run the game a second time I get an error saying. 'EOFError: ran out of input'.